# Can someone explain the sequence of events that occurs in the encoding/decoding process?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to solidify my understanding of encoding and decoding. I'm not sure how the sequence of events works in different settings:

1. When I type on my computer, is the computer(or whatever program I'm in), automatically decoding my letters in UTF-8(or whatever encoding is used)
2. When I save a file, is it automatically saving it using the encoding standard that was used to decode my text? Let's say I send over that document or dataset to someone, am I sending a bunch of 1s and 0s to them? and then their decoder is decoding it based on whatever default or encoding standard they specify?
3. How does code points play into this? Does my computer also have a default code point dictionary it uses?
4. If these above is true, how do I find out what kind of decoding/encoding my computer/program is using?

Sorry if this isn't clear, or if I'm misunderstanding/using terminology incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that this can work, but here is one possibility.

First, yes, in a way, the computer "decodes" each letter you type into some encoding. Each time you press a key on your keyboard, you close a circuit, which signals to other hardware in your computer (e.g., a keyboard controller) that a key was pressed. This hardware then populates a buffer with information about the keyboard event (key up, key down, key repeat) and sends an interrupt to the CPU.

When the CPU receives the interrupt, it jumps to a hardware-defined location in memory and begins executing the code it finds there. This code often will examine which device sent the interrupt and then jump to some other location that has code to handle an interrupt sent by the particular device. This code will then read a "[scan code](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard#Scan_Code_Sets.2C_Scan_Codes_and_Key_Codes)" from the buffer on the device to determine which key event occurred.

The operating system then processes the scan code and delivers it to the application that is waiting for keyboard input. One way it can do this is by populating a buffer with the UTF-8-encoded character that corresponds to the key (or keys) that was pressed. The application would then read the buffer when it receives control back from the operating system.

To answer your second question, we first have to remember what happens as you enter data into your file. As you type, your application receives the letters (perhaps UTF-8-encoded, as mentioned above) corresponding to the keys that you press. Now, your application will need to keep track of which letters it has received so that it can later save the data you've entered to a file. One way that it can do this is by allocating a buffer when the program is started and then copying each character into the buffer as it is received. If the characters are delivered from the OS UTF-8-encoded, then your application could simply copy those bytes to the other buffer. As you continue typing, your buffer will continue to be populated by the characters that are delivered by the OS. When it's time to save your file, your application can ask the OS to write the contents of the buffer to a file or to send them over the network. Device drivers for your disk or network interface know how to send this data to the appropriate hardware device. For example, to write to a disk, you may have to write your data to a buffer, write to a register on the disk controller to signal to write the data in the buffer to the disk, and then repeatedly read from another register on the disk controller to check if the write is complete.

Third, Unicode defines a code point for each character. Each code point can be encoded in more than one way. For example, the code point U+004D ("Latin capital letter M") can be encoded in UTF-8 as 0x4D, in UTF-16 as 0x004D, or in UTF-32 as 0x0000004D (see Table 3-4 in [The Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404)). If you have data in memory, then it is encoded using some encoding, and there are libraries available that can convert from one encoding to another.

Finally, you can find out how your computer processes keyboard input by examining the device drivers. You could start by looking at some Linux drivers, as many are open source. Each program, however, can encode and decode data however it chooses to. You would have to examine the code for each individual program to understand how its encoding and decoding works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer so thoroughly. I'm going to read through this a few times, and learn some of the terms you mentioned. I'll hit the answered checkmark(if that's something that matters to you), once I understand fully.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex question, also because *it depends* on many things.

> When I type on my computer, is the computer(or whatever program I'm in), automatically decoding my letters in UTF-8(or whatever encoding is used)

This is very complex. Some programs get the keyboard code (e.g. games), but most programs uses operating system services, to interpret keyboard codes (considering various keyboard layouts, but also modifying result according Shift, Control, etc.).

So, it depends on operating system and program about which *encoding* you get. For terminal programs, the locale of the process include also encoding of stdin/stdout (standard input and standard output). For graphical interfaces, you may get different encoding (according system encoding).

But **UTF-8 is an encoding**, so you used wrongly the word *decoding in UTF-8*.

> When I save a file, is it automatically saving it using the encoding standard that was used to decode my text? Let's say I send over that document or dataset to someone, am I sending a bunch of 1s and 0s to them? and then their decoder is decoding it based on whatever default or encoding standard they specify?

This is the complex part. Many systems, and computer languages are *old*, so they were designed with just one system encoding. E.g. C language. So there is not really a decoding. Programs uses directly the encoding, and they hard code that letter `A` has a specific value. For computers, only the numeric value matter. Only when data is printed things are interpreted, and in a complex way (fonts, character size, ligatures, next line, ...). [And also if you use string functions, you explicitly tell program to uses the numbers as a string of characters].

Some languages (and HTML: you view a page generated by an external machine, so system encoding is not more the same) introduced the *decoding* part: internally in a program you have one single way to represent a string (e.g. with Unicode Code Points). But to have such uniform format, we need to decode strings (but so, now we can handle different encoding, and not being restricted to the encoding of the system).

If you save a file, it will have a sequences of bytes. To interpret (also known as *decoding*) you need to know which encoding has the file. In general you should know it, or give (e.g. as HTML) an out-of-band information ("the following file is UTF-8", e.g. in HTTP headers, or in extension, or in field definition of a database, or...). Some systems (Microsoft Windows) uses BOM (Byte order mark) to distinguish between UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-8, and old system encoding (some people call it ANSI, but it is not ANSI, and it could be many different code pages).

The decoder: usually it should know the encoding, else either it use defaults, or it guess it. HTML has a list on step to perform to get an estimate. BOM method above could help. And some tools will check looking common combination of characters (in various languages). But this is still *magic*. Without BOM or out-of-band data, we can just estimate, and we get wrong often.

> How does code points play into this? Does my computer also have a default code point dictionary it uses?

Code point is the base of Unicode. Every "character" has a code point: a fix number, with a description. This is abstract. In UTF-32 you use the same number for encoding (using 32bit integers), on all other encoding, you have a functions (or a map) from code point to encoded values (and also the way back). Code point is just a numeric value which describes the semantic (so the meaning) of a character. To transmit such information, usually we need an encoding (or just a escaping sequence, e.g. U+FFFF represent (as text) the BOM character).

> If these above is true, how do I find out what kind of decoding/encoding my computer/program is using?

Nobody can answer: your computer will uses a lot of encoding.

MacOS, Unix, POSIX systems: modern systems (and not root account): they will use probably UTF-8. Root will probably use just ASCII (7-bit).

Windows: Internally it uses often UTF16. The output, it depends on the program, but nearly always it uses an 8-bit encoding (so not the UTF16). Windows can read and write several encoding. You can ask the system the default encoding (but programs could still write in UTF-8 or other encoding, if they want). Terminal and settings could gives you different default encoding on different programs.

For this reason, if you program in Windows, you should explicitly save files as UTF-8 (my recommendation), and possibly with BOM (but if you need interoperability with non-Windows machines, in such case, ignore BOM, but you should already know that such files must be UTF-8).